# Eclipse Kepler > EGit Shows Differences in non Changed Files

Tags: eclipse, egit, tortoisegit, eclipse-kepler

I have changed my eclipse version from Indigo to Kepler since it is 64bit. Now, when I clone a project, it shows me like there are some changes in my local project. When I synchronize, I can see the files that looks changed but there are no changes inside the files. I think this is because of eGit.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try refreshing your workspace in eclipse.

Comment: I already created a new workspace.

Comment: I found the problem. It is because of line ending differences bw unix and windows. Changing git configuration resolves the problem.

Comment: See [JGit bug 372834](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=372834) which is about this.

Comment: @enginbilici where are these settings please?

Comment: Tried with update to Egit 4.0.1.20150624025-r. Didn't help. Tried with team / reset / hard. Didn't help. Quite annoying bug.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to do a reset to the latest remote HEAD and these non-differences will disappear.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution was *three times* "Replace with" / "HEAD revision". (be careful to commit everything first)